# How do I send multiple params in my rails3 form controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to send a number of virtual attributes from my form but keep running in to an error about not being able to convert symbol to integer.

My controller's got this in it:

```
 @user = User.generate_batch(params[:user][:username_l][:quantity])
```

And in my model:

```
 def self.generate_batch(username_l, quantity)
```

What am I doing wrong and where can I read up on this??

S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, when passing multiple params, I needed to do the following. I hope it helps someone else.

```
    @user = User.generate_batch(params[:user][:username_l],params[:user][:quantity])
```

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, generate_batch has 2 arguments and you provide only one, and in the wrong place I believe.

Comment: You'll have to excuse me, my crystal ball is a bit shady today, could you describe what the two params represent, so I can tell you where to get them from?

Comment: No need for sarcasm, I'm just asking for advice